# How do you disable custom map music?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

On other people's servers there are commands such as `!stopsound` and `!stopmusic` in order to disable custom map music being played, like on kz_ maps or ze_ maps.

However, when playing on your own server, I have no access to those commands.  `stopsound` doesn't do its job because it disables all sound including footsteps, ambient noises, and environment noises.  I'm looking for a command I can use by myself that disable custom map music specifically. I'm aware that custom map music is "baked" into the map in Hammer.